# call js into theme from flexsilder library folder

Tags: theming

I have flexslider library in my library folder. 
how to add jquery.flexslider.js file in my theme or how to call in my template.php file.

Answer (score 0):

If the library has been created than you can use [libraries_load()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!libraries!libraries.module/function/libraries_load/7) as below:

```
// Load the library of flexislider plugin.
libraries_load('flexslider');
```

libraries_load: Loads a library.

Parameters:

- $name: The name of the library to load.
- $variant: The name of the variant to load. Note that only one variant of a library can be loaded within a single request. The variant that has been passed first is used; different variant names in subsequent calls are ignored.

Comment: This is assuming the library has been created before using [`hook_library`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_library/7)